# Finding Independent exponential random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Independent exponential random variables with respective parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, find the distribution of $Z = \frac{X_1}{X_2}$

My approach would be to make F(Z) = double integral not 100% sure though what the boundary are

Comment: http://www.tc.umn.edu/~nydic001/docs/unpubs/Ratio_of_Exponentials.pdf

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
1-F_Z(z):=P(Z> z)
&= P(X_1 > zX_2)\\
&= \int_0^\infty P(X_1 > zx_2) p_{X_2}(x_2) \mathop{dx_2}\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda_1 zx_2} \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x_2} \mathop{dx_2}\\
&= \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1z+\lambda_2}.
\end{align}

$$p_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} F_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \frac{1}{1+\lambda_2/(\lambda_1 z)} = \frac{1}{(1+\lambda_2/(\lambda_1 z))^2}\cdot \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 z^2} = \frac{\lambda_2/\lambda_1}{(z+\lambda_2/\lambda_1)^2}$$

Comment: y is the boundary between 0 to infinity ? if X1 great than x2

Comment: @darkflames363 There is no condition that $X_1 > X_2$. I am conditioning over all possible values of $X_2$. [If you write out the double integral, it would be the same thing; both integrals would be from $0$ to $\infty$.]

Comment: huh i don't understand in the textbook they don't use infinity because X2 lower than X1   the boundary for x2 should be 0 to x1 is it not?

Comment: The double integral is indeed: $$1-F_Z(z) ~=~ \mathsf P(X_1>zX_2) ~=~ \int_0^\infty\int_{z x_2}^\infty f_{X_1}(x_1)~f_{X_2}(x_2)~\mathrm d x_1~\mathrm d x_2$$ The text book may be using $$F_Z(z) ~=~\mathsf P(X_1\leq zX_2) ~=~ \int_0^\infty \int_0^{z x_2} f_{X_1}(x_1)~f_{X_2}(x_2)~\mathrm d x_1~\mathrm d x_2$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp which one do we use? i know that the text book uses the second one and just does 1 - 2nd one and get a different result than what angryavian

Comment: @darkflames363 You use whichever is easier to integrate; they will give the same answer, though the second seems slightly more work.

Comment: it strange tho cuz the first one i did it and got $frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1*z + \lambda_2}$   but in the text it shows 1 - that

Comment: @darkflames363 Your suggested edit is the same as my answer. If you multiply $\frac{\lambda_2/\lambda_1}{(z+\lambda_2/\lambda_1)^2}$ by $\lambda_1^2/\lambda_1^2$ you get $\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{(\lambda_1 z + \lambda_2)^2}$.

Comment: O xD i thought it was easier to read that way :P sorry!